# keep menu visible in window when scrolling

Tags: jquery

I want to disable window scrollbar, and give scrollbar to some of my div. how? I used "overflow:hidden", then my div content also hidden. Using ASP.Net, MVC, C# with jquery.

Comment: do you just want your content to scroll on top of your background without the background moving? Or do you really want scroll bars on the div's?

Answer (score 0):

```
scrolling="no"
```

but if you use "scrolling=no" of what I know, the content cannot be moved up and down.

Can you try something like this?

```
<div style="width:300px;height:250px;overflow:auto;">
content goes here
</div>
```

If the content is too tall, there will be a vertical scrollbar. If the content is too wide and cannot wrap, there will be a horizontal scrollbar.

By the way, I am guessing you already tried

```
<body style="overflow: hidden">
```